# Registry optimization with Guice

Tags: java, registry, guice

- Hi!
  Today I thought about a kind of optimization and have some questions...

---

Context : 
I'm developing in Java using Guice 2.

---

In my web application, I have a registry of converter to convert on the fly to a certain type. A converter is described as follows:

```
public class StringToBoolean implements Converter<String, Boolean>
{

  @Override
  public Boolean convert(String from) 
  {
      return Boolean.valueOf(from);
  }

}
```

---

My registry is none other than a Map:

```
public class ConverterRegistryImpl implements ConverterRegistry
{  

  private Map<Key,Converter<?,?>> converterRegistry = new HashMap<Key, Converter<?,?>>();

  @Override
  public <F, T> void register(Class<F> fromType, Class<T> toType, Converter<F, T> converter) 
  {
      converterRegistry.put(new Key(fromType,toType), converter);
  }

}
```

---

Finally I register my converter in my registry (class: ServletModule:configureServlets())
**I think this step could be optimized...**

```
ConverterRegistryImpl registry = new ConverterRegistryImpl();
registry.register(String.class, Integer.class, new StringToInteger());
registry.register(String.class, Boolean.class, new StringToBoolean());
...
//Then I bind the registry to this current instance...
bind(ConverterRegistry.class).toInstance(registry)
```

---

In this way I can use it everywhere like this :

```
@Inject 
ConverterRegistry converter;
```

---

- Well I'm searching the best way to implement this using Guice.
- More generally, how did you build that sort of registry with Guice (or without) ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hm, there is no version 1.2 of Guice...

Comment: Yes, I make a mistake. I'm using version 2, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what exactly do you mean by "optimize". One of drawbacks of your approach is that you create your converters and registry by hand, so you do not use benefits of dependency injection for them. Also you can not accumulate converters from different modules.

This can be fixed with multibindings extension to guice: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings

```
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new Module() {
        @Override
        public void configure(Binder binder) {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Multibinder<Converter> converterBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder, Converter.class);
            converterBinder.addBinding().to(StringBooleanConverter.class);
            converterBinder.addBinding().to(BooleanStringConverter.class);
        }
    });
    ConverterRegistryImpl registry = injector.getInstance(ConverterRegistryImpl.class);
```

The full code is avaliable at: https://gist.github.com/1217563

Comment: Ok, then to retrieve a specific converter. I have to check on each converters if it can convert the 2 types (from type & to type) ??

Comment: No. As you may see I used your method in setter:
    void register(Class<?> fromType, Class<?> toType, Converter<?, ?> converter)

Comment: Oh ok ! We have to maintain the Map or Is it better to check on each converter? ! That's a good solution - I will update my project. Thank you !

Comment: Depending on how many converters you will have. Map scales better, but I don't see the way to remove boilerplate code for getFirstClass() and getSecondClass() with it.

Comment: And what about a MapBinder : mapbinder.addBinding(Key(String.class,Integer.class)).to(StringToInteger.class); > Is it possible ?

Comment: MapBinder is a better solution but you can't use Key(A.class, B.class). You should rather define a Pair class that holds A and B classes (or even better, TypeLiterals), and then use a MapBinder for Map<Pair, Converter>. Then you can directly obtain the converter from A to B.